# How to get start and end of subsection of 2d array where a condition holds

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

Given a 2d array of 1s and 0s I need to get the coordinates of the subsection where the 1s are. For example, given the array defined below:

```
a = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

My function should return the start, where the subsection of 1s begins as (1,1) and the end, where the subsection of 1s ends as (2,2)

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this than a for loop by using perhaps numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [`this post`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/132934/), here's one way -

```
def start_end(a):
    m,n = a.shape
    mask = a.astype(bool)

    rowm = mask.any(1)
    colm = mask.any(0)

    r0 = rowm.argmax()
    c0 = colm.argmax()

    r1 = m-rowm[::-1].argmax()-1
    c1 = n-colm[::-1].argmax()-1
    return (r0,c0), (r1,c1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [114]: a # bit more generic case
Out[114]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1]])

In [115]: start_end(a)
Out[115]: ((0, 1), (2, 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the numpy `nonzero()` method to get a list of row, column pairs where the indices are nonzero. Then you can get the min max on these indices.

```
ys, xs = np.array(a).nonzero()
min_point = (ys[0], xs[0])
max_point = (ys[-1], xs[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I added another row for validation:

```
a = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

You could do:

```
results_list = list()
for i, v in enumerate(a):
    if 1 in v:
        results_list.append([i, v.index(1)])
```

Then, for the first and last values:

```
results_list[0] # [1, 1]

results_list[-1] # [3, 3]
```

Or, in one swoop:

```
results_list= list()
while True:
    for i, v in enumerate(a):
        if 1 in v:
            results_list.append([i, v.index(1)])
    # Set firs and last locations to variables for use somewhere else.
    first_pair, last_pair = results_list[0], results_list[-1]
    break
```

Output:

```
In [0]: print(f"First pair: {first_pair}\nLast pair: {last_pair}")

Out [0]: 
First pair: [1, 1]
Last pair: [3, 3]
```